# Instagram API just can't follow user

Tags: objective-c, api, instagram

I have tried anything, but i couldn't follow a user. i am making this request from a mobile device, with :

```
https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/29440194/relationship?access_token=myValideToken&action=follow
```

and i keep getting the status :

```
{"meta":{"code":200},"data":{"outgoing_status":"none","target_user_is_private":false,"incoming_status":"none"}}
```

where i have to get the outgoing status to be: `requested` :

I could see something about their api, that you can't make post requests from client side, something that i couldn't understand. We have an iPhone app that has to make that post request, is there another way to do that ?

**We managed to get with this same token , the time line of the user .**

EDIT:
We have also set the scope of the usee token to have "relationships", but we just keep getting the same respond again and again. just can't manage to follow anyone, and there is no support from them.

```
//ios
        NSString *follow=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/%@/relationship?access_token=%@&action=follow",userID, token];
        NSLog(@"%@",follow);
          NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:follow];
         NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
         NSString *ret = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
         NSLog(@"answer=%@", ret);
```

Comment: This is insane, we have tried  EVERYTHING. I have never had that kind of problem, we just can't continue development. Their API seems so unfinished. there is no one you can speak with . We are completely lost .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well i have manage to solve it with :

```
NSString *initialURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/%@/relationship?access_token=%@",userID,token];
NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:initialURL];

NSString *key = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"action=follow"];
NSData *mastData = [key dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];
NSString *mastLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu",(unsigned long)[mastData length]];

NSMutableURLRequest *request =  [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init]  ;
[request setURL:url];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setValue:mastLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request setHTTPBody:mastData];
NSURLConnection *con=[[NSURLConnection alloc]initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
[con start];
```

I just can't figure out why instagram dont let you know that you must add the action in the request value.